# Nelder-Mead optimization with equality constraints

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I would like to use the function [fminsearch](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) 
of matlab to search for the best hyperparameters of my SVM with a weighted RBF kernel classifier. fminsearch uses the Nelder-Mead simplex method.

Let's say I have the following hyperparameters: C, gamma, w<sub>1</sub>....w<sub>n</sub> where w<sub>i</sub> are the weights of the kernel.

Additionally, I have the constraint that sum(w<sub>i</sub>) = 1, i.e. all weights must sum up to one.

Is there a possibility to use Nelder-Mead with this equality constraint? I know that there is the [fminsearchbnd](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17804-fminsearchbnd-new) 
method for Matlab but I think it can handle only boundary inequality constraints.

Edit: I'm using a SVM classifier and the weights are used in a weighted RBF kernel (one weight for each feature). The parameters to estimate are thus C, gamma and the weights. The cost function is the accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you substitute out one of the `w(i)`? That means, replace e.g. `w1` by `1-w2-w3-...` (and drop the constraint). Otherwise have a look at `fmincon` which allows explicit constraints. In addition you may need `0 <= w(i) <= 1`.

Comment: Yes, I need 0 <= w(i) <= 1, thanks for the hint. And yes, I could do w1 = 1-w2-w3-...but why can I then drop the constraint sum(w(i)) = 1? For example, w2 = 0.8 and w3 = 0.5 and then w1 = 1 - w2 - w3 = 1 - 0.8 - 0.5 < 0

Comment: Regarding fmincon: Do you know which algorithm is used for solving? I assume not Nelder-Mead. Does fmincon assume linear and smooth cost function? This may not be the case because my cost function is the balanced accuracy measure (in a SVM classification setting).

Comment: If you have bounds on the w(i), then you cannot substitute them out (but the bounds were not mentioned in the original post). `fmincon` has several algorithms you can choose from. The documentation is actually very good. Nonsmooth problems can always cause problems (but not always do). If possible one can try to reformulate into something smooth.

Comment: Please see my updated post for further explanation. Of course I could let w(i) go above 1 and then just rescale the weights to sum to one. Would this work or would then nelder-mead no more working?